# ZAP - Backup files scanning

Tags: zap

I seem unable to determine whether ZAP's *activescan* capabilities include the automated search for backup files.

In ZAP's current help, there is no advertisement for such capabilities: 
https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpAddonsAscanrulesAscanrules

Alpha development rules, updated three months ago, do not mention them either: 
zaproxy/zap-extensions/tree/alpha/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrulesAlpha

Yet, as backup file scanning seemed to be included in 2014, I don't see why it wouldn't today: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-develop/poF_OU_4kfs

--
Is backup files scanning bundled with ZAP? If yes, how? 
Thanks in advance, 
Ioni

Answer (score 0):

Being answered on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/2iNDOcPMWvg/AuJd_DLwBwAJ